# Nginx unable to host HTML file

Tags: html, nginx, webserver

I get the following error when I try to host HTML or text files:

> 2017/09/27 21:30:06 [emerg] 4652#13640: unexpected end of file,
>   expecting ";" or "}" in C:/nginx/html/reports/Summary.html:1068

It looks like its unable to identify the type of the file may be (my guess)
Also the `server_name` field doesn't seem to work as expected.

Have I missed something?

This is how the file header looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Content Summary</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
```

This is my nginx conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include C:/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 600;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    server {
        listen       89;
        server_name  reports.devops.com;

        location / {
            include C:/nginx/html/reports/Summary.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should set a root rather than including the html file (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) - Note that include is only for including nginx configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Include is for including nginx config. So you need to change your config file to below

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include C:/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 600;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    server {
        listen       89;
        server_name  reports.devops.com;

        location / {
            root C:/nginx/html/reports/;
            index index.html Summary.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/;
        }
    }
}
```

The `root C:/nginx/html/reports/;` directive will tell nginx that you are looking to serve files from this directory. `index index.html Summary.html;` directive will tell it to search for files like `index.html` and `Summary.html` is no file is not specified. And `try_files $uri $uri/;` will tell nginx to either check the url as a file or a folder.

Comment: I used the above config and got this error:

`eports\/reports/tSummary.html//////////" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect), client: 192.168.99.1, server: , request: "GET /reports/Summary.html HTTP/1.1", host: "devops.com:89"
2017/09/28 04:22:50 [error] 6560#5164: *21 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/reports/Summary.html///////////", client: 192.168.99.1, server: , request: "GET /reports/Summary.html HTTP/1.1", host: "devops.com:89"`

Does it need escaping or backslashes? I tried that too.The file does exist